# How do I forcibly kill a Jenkins build in cloudbees?

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I have a project in Cloudbees Jenkins that has been stuck for 12 hours. The build seems to have done most of what it was supposed to do (uploading the artifact to the repository), but the last line on the log file says:

> Build timed out due to Global Timeout (after 480 minutes). Marking the build as aborted.

When I click the red 'X' to terminate the build, nothing happens.

I've dealt with this before when I ran my own Jenkins servers by restarting the slave and host manually, but I don't see how to do that with Cloudbees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surest way to deal with this is to just use the /restart URL to restart your instance.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that URL existed. Is there a link to that URL anywhere on Grandcentral (or somewhere else?) Or is there documentation I should have found about that?